Tensorflow: Accuracy around 0.75 but loss not below 0.5
I've implemented in Python a FCNN.
My database is made of around 5000 football matches with the following features: shots, corners, cards, fouls, big chances created, passes, cross and saves.
My outcome is binary: how wins or away wins or draws.
I am using "binary_crossentropy" as loss function and activation "sigmoid" in my output layer (1 neuron). I've implemented dropout and early stopping as well.
Both my training and validation accuracy is around 0.75 (which sounds not bad at all) but both loss values don't go down 0.5, which as far as I know is not very good.
Is there any optimization I can implement to make the loss decreasing ?
[EDIT]: I have added 2 more features that seem to be a game changer: home and away shot conversion rates (goals/shots). Now the loss is around 0.1 (or less).
The only point is that plotting the feature importance using RandomForest it seems that these 2 are far more relevant than the others. Which doesn't sound good to me

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys
import joblib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

if len(sys.argv) == 4:
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    pattern = sys.argv[2]
    network_path = sys.argv[3]
else:
    print("[ERROR] Incorrect parameters")
    quit

# Step 1: Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

print("Available columns:", df.columns)

# Remove corrupted lines
df = df[df['MatchId'] != ""]

# Aggregate shots in just 2 columns, for home and away
df['HomeTeamShots'] = df['HomeTeamShotsOnTarget'] + df['HomeTeamShotsOffTarget'] + df['HomeTeamBlockedShots']
df['AwayTeamShots'] = df['AwayTeamShotsOnTarget'] + df['AwayTeamShotsOffTarget'] + df['AwayTeamBlockedShots']

# Shot conversion rate [newly added]
# df['HomeTeamConversionRate'] = 0  # Default value for conversion rate
# df.loc[df['HomeTeamShots'] > 0, 'HomeTeamConversionRate'] = df['HomeTeamFTGoal'] / df['HomeTeamShots']

# df['AwayTeamConversionRate'] = 0  # Default value for conversion rate
# df.loc[df['AwayTeamShots'] > 0, 'AwayTeamConversionRate'] = df['AwayTeamFTGoal'] / df['AwayTeamShots']

# Home wins
if pattern == "HW":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] > row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] \
    else 1,
    axis=1
)
# Home wins or draws
elif pattern == "HWD":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] >= row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )
# Away wins
elif pattern == "AW":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] < row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )
# Over 2.5 goals
elif pattern == "OV25":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] + row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] > 2 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )
# BTTS
elif pattern == "BTTS":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] > 0 and row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] > 0 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )
# Over 3.5 goals
elif pattern == "OV35":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] + row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] > 3 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    
# Draw
elif pattern == "DRAW":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] == row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    
# Home over 0.5
elif pattern == "HOV05":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] > 0 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    
# Away over 0.5
elif pattern == "AOV05":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] > 0 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    
# Home over 0.5
elif pattern == "HOV15":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['HomeTeamFTGoal'] > 1 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    
# Away over 0.5
elif pattern == "AOV15":
    df['Outcome'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['AwayTeamFTGoal'] > 1 \
        else 1,
        axis=1
    )    

# Drop not relevant columns
df = df.drop(columns=['HomeTeamID', 'AwayTeamID', 'MatchId', 'HomeTeamFTGoal', 'AwayTeamFTGoal', 'HomeTeamName', 'AwayTeamName', 'MatchDate', 'HomeTeamxG', 'AwayTeamxG',
                    'HomeTeamBlockedShots', 'AwayTeamBlockedShots', 
                    'HomeTeamShotsInsideBox', 'AwayTeamShotsInsideBox', 'HomeTeamShotsOutsideBox','AwayTeamShotsOutsideBox', 'HomeTeamShotsOnTarget', 'AwayTeamShotsOnTarget',
                     'HomeTeamShotsOffTarget', 'AwayTeamShotsOffTarget' ])

# Split features and target
X = df.drop(columns=['Outcome']).values  # Features
y = df['Outcome'].values  # Target

# Encode target variable as categorical
# y_one_hot = to_categorical(y)
y_one_hot = y

# Split training and testing datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_one_hot, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# and scale
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

############### Random forest for feature evaluation ###############

# Store column names before scaling
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
feature_names = df.drop(columns=['Outcome']).columns

X_scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns=feature_names)

rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

# Get feature importances
importances_rf = rf_model.feature_importances_

# Print or plot the feature importances
print("Feature Importances from Random Forest:")
for feature, importance in zip(feature_names, importances_rf):
    print(f"{feature}: {importance}")

# Optionally, plot the importances
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.barh(feature_names, importances_rf)
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance')
plt.title('Feature Importance from Random Forest')
plt.show()

############### Random forest for feature evaluation ###############

############### Models ###############

model = Sequential([
    Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    # Dropout(0.6),  # Increased dropout to regularize more
    Dropout(0.2),  # Increased dropout to regularize more
    Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    # Dropout(0.5),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    # Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # Output layer for multi-class classification
])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Implement early stopping and learning rate reduction
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=0.5, patience=3, min_lr=1e-6, verbose=1)

history = model.fit(
    X_train_scaled, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test),
    epochs=50,
    batch_size=32,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr],
    verbose=1
)

# Plot accuracy and loss
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss', color='blue')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss', color='orange')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss Over Epochs', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Epochs', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Loss', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(fontsize=12)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

predictions = model.predict(X_test_scaled)
plt.hist(predictions, bins=50)
plt.title("Distribution of Predicted Probabilities")
plt.show()

# Plot training and validation accuracy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Save the model to a file
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
filename = network_path + "\\" + pattern + "_Model_" + timestamp + ".h5"
print(f"Network path: {filename}")
print(network_path)
model.save(filename)


Do both classes appear equally often? Can you add plots of your losses? And maybe show relevant parts of your code? Otherwise it is diffcult to get you some pointers. Also maybe this is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258166/good-accuracy-despite-high-loss-value

Sure. I can pass my entire Python code, do you know the best way to do it? Copy it here? Thanks

Yes, copy your code and follow the guidelines on how to format it correctly.
Regarding your edit: since goals determine who wins a game, it is not surprising that this helps. But it also does not make sense to use this feature, because you do not know in advance of a game how many goals there will be. Or am I understanding this wrong? Try to explain your data better.

Exactly. This is why in the original script, I've removed them and I will rollback to this code version. I've attached the code on my original post

Anyway I was trying to predicting the "Home wins" outcome in both ways: with (very low loss) or without (loss ~0.5) shot conversion rates. With the conversion rates I receive back in output basically 1or 0, while without I get back intermediated values (ex. 0.86 / 0.14). I'm not sure if I am right but I found really more useful having a probability estimate that giving back to me the certainty of which will be the outcome

I think there are two things you can try:
Change your hyperparameters and see how this affects your model performance.
But I think more importantly generate new features. For instance how often did each team win in the previuos ten games, how is it ranked (like what place does it have in its league) and other statistics you can generate from the data you have. Be creative. You could also try to include external data like the weather, or how far away is the visting team from its hometown (less supporters).

I'm quite limited on adding features on the training dataset. For instance, I pretty doubt I can retrieve weather information for each of ~5000 games in my dataset. For the future match this is quite feasible, but unfortunately not for the past ones...

It is just a suggestion, don't take it to literal :)
